# How do I minimize Notoriety?

Tags: pandemic-2

I'd like to make sure my disease stays out of the immunization research phase as long as possible. What does it take to make sure Notoriety stays at a minimum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notoriety is caused by symptoms, and the more lethal a symptom the more notoriety. Use fewer, less lethal symptoms to spread, and your notoriety will stay low.